# Missing user interface when runnig OMNeT++ example

Tags: user-interface, omnet++

I was trying to integrate one of the OMNeT++ systemc example onto our framework ([SoCRocket](https://socrocket.github.io/)) and after some effort i succeeded to build one of the examples but when i try to run it i get the following error:

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2018 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 5.4.1, build: 180629-5e28390, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer


<!> Error: No user interface (Cmdenv, Tkenv, etc.) found

End.
```

Just to know, I disabled the shared libraries option and i have built OMNeT++ in release mode. i have the following libraries in `/omnet/lib/`:

```
omnet/lib/
├── liboppcmdenv.a
├── liboppcommon.a
├── liboppenvir.a
├── liboppeventlog.a
├── libopplayout.a
├── liboppmain.a
├── liboppnedxml.a
├── liboppqtenv.a
├── liboppqtenv-osg.a
├── liboppscave.a
├── liboppsim.a
└── liboppsystemc.a
```

Is something missing, Anyone have an idea?

## Edit

Script used to build a code in the framework:

```
def build(bld):
      
    bld(
        target       = 'example1.platform',
        features     = 'cxx cprogram',
        source       = '/forkjoin/forkjoin.cc SC_Wrapper.cc',
        includes     = '.',
        use          = [
                       'oppsystemc','oppmain','oppenvir','oppsim','oppcommon','oppnedxml','oppcmdenv','oppeventlog','opplayout','oppqtenv','oppqtenv-osg','oppscave','xml2','mpi','mpi_cxx','dl'
                       ],
    )
```

Comment: When you are about to install OMNeT++, you have to run the "configure" script first. Were you able to do this without any error?

Comment: Could you show how did you build this example (i.e. what options of opp_makemake did you use)?

Comment: Yes i had all the needed dependencies ... except for the optional ones ... are you asking for a specific detail?

Comment: this is the problem, the framework does not use a makefile to build but a waf script that is used as makefile... i will add the example in my question

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the linker simply "optimizes out" the user interface libraries.

There are some dummy functions in each user interface library, called `qtenv_lib`, `tkenv_lib`, and `cmdenv_lib`, precisely to give a "handle" for each library.

Try adding some linker flags to "force-link" these libraries, by "undefining" some of these symbols. Something like the `--undefined` or `--require-defined` options should do it. The standard OMNeT++ build process also adds these, for the same reason. You might need to prepend an underscore (`_`) to the function name to get the symbol name.

**EDIT:**

Oh, with static libraries, maybe you should use `--whole-archive` instead.

Comment: Yep. Exactly. You should specify -Wl,-u,_qtenv_lib and -Wl,-u,_cmdenv_lib for the compiler (or -u,_qtenv_lib and -u,_cmdenv_lib for the linker) to prevent the linker to optimize out the required code.